# When Click on "Edit", the inputfields on the Editpage should be prefilled (VueJS, Pinia Store, API Platform)

Tags: vue.js, fetch-api, pinia, vue-script-setup

Want to build a simple CRUD App to understand the Basics. I am using Vue3 + Pinia Store + API Platform.
[image]
What i have:

- StudentsPage: here, i fetch Data from my API and display the Data in a Table (using pinia store): **works ok**.
- Add Student: Form for "add Student" to my API using Basic inputfields (using pinia store): **works ok**
- Button for "Delete", deleting selected Data (using pinia store): **works ok**
- Button for "Edit", routing to EditPage with ID from selected Data: **works partially**
  Route to EditPage is okay. On EditPage i make Fetch request with the ID from the selected Data. I can ConsoleLog the data. But the **inputfileds are not prefilled** with the data in the copied Form from "add Student".

What i want:

- **Inputfields should be prefilled** with data from the fetch request for the specific id.
- I dont know how to assign the "single" Fetch to my students Array, which is defined in the Pinia Store. The Fetch for All Data works perfect. The Fetch for single too. but the Inputfields are not prefilled.

EditPage

```
<template>
    <div class="container mt-5">
        <h1>Edit Student (id: {{ currentId }})</h1>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <form id="form" @submit.prevent="studentStore.alertMe(id)">  
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label class="form-label">Name</label>
                        <input v-model="newStudent.name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" aria-describedby="helpId">
                        <small id="helpId" class="text-muted">Name </small>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label for="" class="form-label">Course</label>
                        <input v-model="newStudent.course" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" aria-describedby="helpId">
                        <small id="helpId" class="text-muted">Name Course</small>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="row g-3">
                        <div class="col">
                            <label>e-Mail</label>
                            <input v-model="newStudent.email" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" aria-label="First name">
                            <small id="helpId" class="text-muted">e-Mail</small>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col">
                            <label>Phone</label>
                            <input v-model="newStudent.phone" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" aria-label="Last name">
                            <small id="helpId" class="text-muted">Phonenumber</small>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3 mt-4">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <p>Status</p>
                <div id="responseContainer"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Snippet from Pinia store

```
export const useStudentStore = defineStore('studentStore', {
  state: () => ({
    students: [],
    loading: false,
    name: 'Vue3 (script setup) / Pinia Store / Bootstrap 5.3 / CRUD / Fetch',
    apiurl: "http://xx.x.x.xx/symfony/api_projekt04/public/index.php/api/students",
  }),
```

Function in Pinia Store to Fetch All Data: okay.

```
 // FETCH Method: GET all Students
     async getStudents() {
      const res = await fetch(this.apiurl)      // API + id
      const data = await res.json()             // const "data"

      console.log(data["hydra:member"]);        // clg data    
      // console.log(data["hydra:totalItems"]); // clg data totalItems

      this.students = data["hydra:member"]      // students => data["hydra:member"]
    },
```

Function in Pinia Store to Fetch Single Data with specific ID: okay.

```
// FETCH Method: GET one Student
    async getStudentData(id) {
      const res = await fetch(this.apiurl + '/' + id)   // API + id
      const data = await res.json()                     // const "data"

      console.log(res);      // clg res    
      console.log(data);      // clg data    

      this.students = data["hydra:member"]       // students => data["hydra:member"]
    },
```

Thanks for any help. Tom

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hello. i try: My Focus is to prefill the textfields with the Values for id6. 
When i click the Edit-Button the Edit-Page loads, thats ok, but the textfields are not prefilled with data for id6.
In my Screenshot i click the Edit-Button for the Data with id6. On pageload for the Edit-Page i fetch the data for this id6 (in console.log i see the Data for id6) but textfields are empty. Thats my problem. Thanks